# How to Generate PlayActivity onClick Buttons for a Quiz game?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I am working on Android Quiz.  I am  working on Play button. Now I want to add a PlayActivity  like KBC Show .Now i wanted to Retrieve Question from database onClick of play button  .so Can any one help me out how to make it.

1. How to Design the Layout of KBC Show.
2. How to retrieve the dataBase on the Click of the button.

Thank's in advance

Comment: After reading the concept LinearLayout and RelativeLaout of XML with padding button and their alignment .i am able to designed a Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have button button1  then you can write

```
btton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent=new Intent(FrontActivity.this,PlayActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

This will start PlayActivity

Comment: Thanks for marking as it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Register a listener for the button. In the listener onClick() method write the code to start newActivity using Intents.

Something like this:

```
ImageButton Ibutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
Ibutton.setOnClickListener(this);      

ImageButton Ibutton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_2);
Ibutton2.setOnClickListener(this);      


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button_1:
    // action to preform on button 1
        Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, "Button 1 pressed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.button_2:
    // action to preform on button 1
        Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, "Button 2 pressed ",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chand90u why should we visit your previous question? your question is unclear. post what is required here

Comment: @Chand90u .. you must be kidding me. You should ask your doubt clearly here..

Comment: I didnt understand what does it mean.. "activity like KBC show". is KBC show some application which you want to launch on button click? Or you want to design KBC Show?